# Is there anything like .js.erb templates in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc-3

I am adding jQuery AJAX functionality to my MVC 3 site. When I use rails, I make an AJAX call using the $.getScript function then render a .js.erb which is executed on the client (e.g. http://railscasts.com/episodes/229-polling-for-changes ). Does MVC 3 have anything equivalent to Javascript views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does

```
public ActionResult AjaxMethod() {
    /* do stuff */
    return PartialView("ViewName");
}
```

This will return the HTML of the above view to the calling ajax method

Answer (score 0):

To return javascript to be executed directly in the client, like the Rails erb.js template, the best method would be to return a JavaScriptResult from the controller method

```
public ActionResult AjaxMethod() {
/* do stuff */
return JavaScript(script);
```

}

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.javascriptresult.aspx

Comment: But isn't that kind of ugly? The controller shouldn't be responsible for generating the javascript. It should be responsible for getting the model(s) from the database and passing it to a view for rendering. The reason I like .js.erb files is because you retain the elegance and power of erb when writing javascript.

Comment: Agreed, I'm pretty new to Rails but it seems the ability to return js.erb files is pretty powerful, I can't see that there is any direct equivalent in ASP.NET MVC. I suppose in theory it would be possible to derive a custom ActionResult that would render a Razor view into a JavaScriptResult to return to the client?